# Move file from one folder to another - Error 53 File not Found

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to move the file from one folder to another, with a validation for that file inside my system (so far so good), however VBA presents `Error 53` (file not found), however when using `Debug.Print`, the directory and file is correct, and I also already found the file in the folder obviously.

File name:
`DRIP_SJ0187C3_AZUL_RETANGULO_FEM_RX_52_139_MODELO.jpg`

Folder:
`C:\OCULOS`

Debug.Print result: `C:\OCULOS\DRIP_SJ0187C3_AZUL_RETANGULO_FEM_RX_52_139_MODELO.jpg`

VBA Code:

```
Sub MoveFile()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim Source, Path, File As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim SourceFile As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rng = Planilha2.Range("E2:E1048576")

Source = "C:\OCULOS\"
Path= "C:\OCULOS_SEM_ESTOQUE\"

For Each cell In rng
    i = i + 1
    If Planilha2.Cells(i, 5) = 0 Then
        File = Planilha2.Cells(i, 1).Value
        SourceFile= Source & File
        Debug.Print SourceFile
        FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFile, Destination:=Path
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Debug.Print Dir(SourceFile)`

Comment: Does the destination folder already exist?

Comment: I could only produce this when path and file is incorrect. `Debug.Print` is printing the string not the actual path and filename. So check the string for missing or redundant backslashes (\\). BTW Source and Path are declared as Variant. Change to `Dim Source As String, Path As String, File As String`. This has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Maybe the filename is occurring in column `A` more then once, but after the first time it isn't there anymore (`MoveFile` not `CopyFile`). BTW `Integer` cannot 'handle' so many rows. You should change to `Dim i As Long`. The program is working correctly on my computer even without the changes I'm suggesting (got rid of the loop though).

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, the destination folder exists, if I `Debug.Print Dir(SourceFile)`, the result is blank (I don't know why).

Comment: @VBasic2008 Should I change `Dim Source As String, Path As String, File As String` to `Variant`? I changed `Dim i As Long` as you said. The loop is to check the stock of each piece (which is the name of the images)

Comment: Well, I don't why, but changing the `Dim i As Long`, it worked! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final code:

```
Sub MoveFile()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim Source, Path, File As String
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim SourceFile As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rng = Planilha2.Range("E2:E1048576")

Source = "C:\OCULOS\"
Path = "C:\OCULOS_SEM_ESTOQUE\"

For Each cell In rng
    i = i + 1
    If Planilha2.Cells(i, 5) = 0 Then
        File = Planilha2.Cells(i, 1).Value
        SourceFile = Source & File
'        Debug.Print Dir(SourceFile)
'        Debug.Print File
        FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFile, Destination:=Path
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Where was the error? Why didn't you change `Source` and `Path` to `String`?

Comment: I don't know, I changed to `Dim As Long` as you said. Where change to `String`? Is it not already?

Comment: No, it is not already. `Source` and `Path` are declared as `Variant`. You have to use the following when declaring variables in one line: `Dim Source As String, Path As String, File As String`. Remember this. Here it is almost no harm done, but in a future case you could waste a lot of time on this. I will be posting a solution with arrays today or the day after tomorrow. It's about 80% done. I hope you'll still be interested.